# Keyclock with Redmine interface using SAML login, getting an error

Tags: redmine, keycloak

I am new to this Keyclock & Redmine interface using SAML. As of now my `saml.rb` is we are trying to implement SSO.

```
Redmine::OmniAuthSAML::Base.configure do |config|
  config.saml = {
    :assertion_consumer_service_url => "http://<IP>/redmine/auth/saml/callback", # OmniAuth callback URL
    :issuer                         => "redmine-saml",      # The issuer name / entity ID. Must be an URI as per SAML 2.0 spec.
    :single_logout_service_url      => "http://<IP>/redmine/auth/saml",      # The SLS (logout) callback URL
    :idp_sso_target_url             => "http://<Keyclock IP>:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/saml", # SSO login endpoint
    :idp_cert_fingerprint           => "66:BC:3D:15:AD:FA:70:A6:33:20:21:4F:2E:FC:43:1B:79:EC:D7:12", # SSO ssl certificate fingerprint
    # Alternatively, specify the full certifiate:
    :idp_cert                       => "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",
    :name_identifier_format         => "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent",
    :signout_url                    => "http://<Keyclock IP:8080>/auth/realms/master/protocol/saml/clients/redmine-saml", # Optional signout URL, not supported by all identity providers
    :idp_slo_target_url             => "http://<Keyclock IP:8080>/auth/realms/master/protocol/saml/clients/redmine-saml",
    :name_identifier_value          => "login", # Which redmine field is used as name_identifier_value for SAML logout

:attribute_mapping              => {
    # How will we map attributes from SSO to redmine attributes

     :login      => 'extra.raw_info.username',
     :mail       => 'extra.raw_info.email',
     :firstname  => 'extra.raw_info.firstname',
     :lastname   => 'extra.raw_info.lastname'
    }
  }

  config.on_login do |omniauth_hash, user|
    # Implement any hook you want here
  end
end
```

Here Redmine is able to redirect to the keyclock portal but if I give the password it's throwing an error at redmine portal:

```
translation missing: en.error_saml_invalid_ticket
```

Please let me know where I need to make changes.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow @kranthi! your question needs some changes so it can attract high quality answers. see this post on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). specifically, format your code into code blocks using four initial spaces (or backticks for inline code). more importantly, ask a specific question rather than pasting code and asking us to fix it. can you narrow your issue down to a specific point? what have you tried so far?

Comment: That does not look like error, it shouldn't stop your system from working, however, probably you are using some other language unsupported by saml plugin, try creating language file for your language. Take a look here: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_translate_Redmine_in_your_own_language Same works for plugins...